# jquery validation not working - need to include more files?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am using the jquery validation plugin: https://jqueryvalidation.org/
I've tried different examples but the validation is not working for me. I'm now testing with this extra simple code from this thread (demo down very bottom): [jQuery validation on select box not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945698/jquery-validation-on-select-box-not-working)

Still does not work for me. I've included bootstrap.min.js and jquery.validate.js
The jquery.validate.js package came with a lot of files in its zip. Am I suppose to include other files too? Thanks very much for any feedback / help.

My codes, body part copied from the above example link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<form id="formid">
    <select id="select" name="select" class="required">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="child">test2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
$("#formid").validate(); 
</script> 
<!-- jQuery --> 
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> 

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript --> 

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misplaced the jQuery script tag. Please put it in the head tag and make sure it is above your plugins.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script> //place jquery.js here, followed by plugins

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript --> 

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<form id="formid">
    <select id="select" name="select" class="required">
        <option value="">Choose</option>
        <option value="child">test2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
$("#formid").validate(); 
</script> 
<!-- jQuery --> 


</body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I've been putting the scripts down the bottom because I read somewhere it speeds up the loading. And also Bootstrap templates all have them down the bottom. So I guess it is still safer to put scripts up the top if you're a newbie like me then?

Comment: Nope, jquery scripts wont work unless you put the jquery.js script on TOP of them. Yes, its good practice, regardless you're a newbie or not. No, it doesnt speeds up loading. If you want to speed up the loading, please consider downloading the jQuery.min.js file you can get from the official site, but if you're still learning, I'd recommend to just use the current you have. Thanks!